# Splitting Time Period into Multiple Time Span

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, design-patterns

My Payroll App is working with a Class PayrollLineItems and SpecialShifts.

```
public class PayrollLineitems
{
   public int PayrollLineItemID {get;set;} // eg : 1
   public int CaregiverID       {get;set;} // eg : 1
   public DateTime ScheduleDate {get;set;} // eg : 01-01-2022
   public DateTime StartTime    {get;set;} // eg : 01-01-2022 10:00 
   public DateTime EndTime     {get;set}  // eg :  01-01-2022 18:00
}

public class SpecialShifts
{
  public TimeSpan Start { get; set; } //e.g. 08:00
  public TimeSpan End { get; set; } //e.g. 17:00
  public string Days { get;set; } //e.g. 6,7 => 6-> Saturday, 7 -> Sunday
}
```

For eg :
Below are the details of Schedules Served by the Clinician on different Days

| ScheduleDate | StartTime | EndTime | Day of Week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2022 | 01-01-2022 10:00 | 01-01-2022 18:00 | Sunday |
| 01-02-2022 | 01-02-2022 19:00 | 01-02-2022 21:00 | Monday |

Below are the details of SpecialShifts

| Start | End | Days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13:00 | 14:00 | Saturday,Sunday |
| 16:00 | 17:00 | Saturday,Sunday |
| 15:00 | 20:00 | Monday |

### Result

if Clinician has done any schedules which falls on Special Shift Hours then Clinician will get paid Extra 10$ for the Shift Hours. So it is required to Split the Schedules as below

| ScheduleDate | StartTime | EndTime |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2022 | 01-01-2022 10:00 | 01-01-2022 13:00 | Regular |
| 01-01-2022 | 01-01-2022 13:00 | 01-01-2022 14:00 | Shift |
| 01-01-2022 | 01-01-2022 15:00 | 01-01-2022 16:00 | Regular |
| 01-01-2022 | 01-01-2022 16:00 | 01-01-2022 17:00 | Shift |
| 01-01-2022 | 01-01-2022 17:00 | 01-01-2022 18:00 | Regular |
| 01-02-2022 | 01-02-2022 19:00 | 01-02-2022 20:00 | Shift |
| 01-02-2022 | 01-02-2022 20:00 | 01-02-2022 21:00 | Regular |

Above Schedules marked as Shift will get Paid extra 10$. So how can we split PayrollLineItems(2 records) as mentioned in the result.

Below are the Considerations for splitting Payroll Line item Record

1. one Payroll Line Item record can falls on multiple Split and In this case Payroll Line item should split accordingly to the Shift Start and End Time (Record got splitted for Schedule Date "01-01-2022" in Result Section)
2. if PayrollLineItems record matches the ScheduleDate,Day of Week and Start Time then we need to split.

I am following below method

```
var payrollLineItemsShifts = PayrollLineitems.Where(x=>SpecialShifts.Any(dtls=>dtls.Days==x.DayofWeek));   
Foreach(var item in PayrollLineitems){
  // Spliting Payroll Line Item Start Date to SHift Start time
}
```

With the above method it is taking more time as record in SpecialShifts increases and I am using further loop to Split PayrollLineItem record.

As mentioned in the Result Section.
Schedule on 01-01-2022 is splitting into 4 line items since PayrollLineItem falls on 2 Special Shift records. Split will increase with the increase of Special Shift records falls in the PayrollLineItem.Start and EndDate.

I tried TimePeriod library but it didn't work. is there any design pattern or algorithm can be used to simplify the above Problem?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Using TimeSpans and a string to represent one or more days for special shifts is really awkward. If you have control over that, you should try to make a structure that more closely matches your PayrollLineItems structure. If not, then I'd recommend writing an extension method or two to get similar DateTimes - then put all the items in a List and filter/sort the list as you see fit.

Comment: So you basically want to merge both objects to create a timeline? Each PayrollLineitems has a single SpecialShifts associated (1:1 cardinality)? And do you map them (shouldn't SpecialShifts be a member of PayrollLineitems i.e. use composition) ? And SpecialShifts always falls between start and end of PayrollLineitems? Are asking for an algorithm to create the timeline or for a design pattern to design your application?

Comment: Thanks @BionicCode. One payrolllineitem can map to multiple special shift. I am looking for an alogirthim using pattern matching to get the required results. One payrolllineitem record need to be splitted based upon the special shift start and end time.

Comment: Then simply sort the SpecialShifts by the SpecialShifts.Start property. Then start with the PayrollLineitems.StartTime, insert the SpecialShifts and complete with SpecialPayrollLineitems.EndTime. Where is your problem?

Comment: @BionicCode Thanks for the suggestion.
one PayrollLineItem record can map to multiple Special Rate Shifts.
For eg -> Payroll Line Item -> Start Time => 10AM, End Time -> 6PM matches to the Special Shifts, First Shift -> 10Am to 11PM, Second Shift -> 4P to 5PM
then i need to split PayrollLineItem as 3 records. So will you please suggest any design pattern for the above problem.
At present i am using multiple foreach to solve above problem.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for the suggestion.
one PayrollLineItem record can map to multiple Special Rate Shifts.
For eg -> Payroll Line Item -> Start Time => 10AM, End Time -> 6PM matches to the Special Shifts, First Shift -> 10Am to 11PM, Second Shift -> 4P to 5PM
then i need to split PayrollLineItem as 3 records. So will you please suggest any design pattern for the above problem.
At present i am using multiple foreach to solve above problem.

Comment: I can't because you didn't show how the two types relate to each other. You must show the exact input i.e. how the data to handle looks like or is structured. For example I would expect that PayrollLineItem  has a collection of SpecialShifts. This is the most natural OO class design. But obviously you decided against it. Then how do those two types map. Your desired output is now better to understand. But the input is not clear. Maybe you can show your current implementation to show how you receive the data. Please improve your question so that I or anybody else is enabled to help you.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @BionicCode I updated the Question with the required Details. Any help is much appreciated.